# Error saving crawled page using file_urls and ITEM_PIPELINES: Missing scheme in request url: h

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to have scrapy download a copy of each page it crawls but when I run my spider the log contains entries like

```
2016-06-20 15:39:12 [scrapy] ERROR: Error processing {'file_urls': 'http://example.com/page',
 'title': u'PageTitle'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\scrapy\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\scrapy\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\media.py", line 44, in process_item
    requests = arg_to_iter(self.get_media_requests(item, info))
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\scrapy\lib\site-packages\scrapy\pipelines\files.py", line 365, in get_media_requests
    return [Request(x) for x in item.get(self.files_urls_field, [])]
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\scrapy\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "c:\anaconda3\envs\scrapy\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 57, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h
```

Other questions in SO about this error seem to relate to problems with the `start_urls` but my start url is fine as the spider crawls across the site, it just doesn't save the page to my specified files_store.

I populate the `file_urls` using `item['file_urls'] = response.url`

**Do I need to specify the url a different way?**

Comment: Set a list of URLs, i.e `item['file_urls'] = [response.url]`

Comment: Thanks @paultrmbrth that got the files created on disk. Could I expand on the question for some help to clean up the output ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Opening a new question is recommended if the problem is different

Comment: Opened a question thats related to the [response.url] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938638/how-to-tidy-up-csv-output-from-scrapy-when-using-files-item-pipeline