# How to tidy up csv output from scrapy when using files item pipeline

Tags: scrapy

After alot of help from the SO community I have a scrapy crawler which saves the webpage of the site it crawls but I'd like to clean up the csv file that gets created `--output`

**A sample row currently looks like**

```
"[{'url': 'http://example.com/page', 'path': 'full/hashedfile', 'checksum': 'checksumvalue'}]",http://example.com/page,2016-06-20 16:10:24.824000,http://example.com/page,My Example Page
```

> **How do I get the csv file to contain details on 1 file per line (no extra url:)and the path value includes an extension like .html or .txt ?**

**my items.py is as follows**

```
class MycrawlerItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    crawldate = scrapy.Field()
    pageurl = scrapy.Field()
    files = scrapy.Field()
    file_urls = scrapy.Field()
```

**My rules callback is**

```
def scrape_page(self,response):
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body,"html.parser")
    ScrapedPageTitle = page_soup.title.get_text()
    item = MycrawlerItem()
    item['title'] =ScrapedPageTitle
    item['crawldate'] = datetime.datetime.now()
    item['pageurl'] = response.url
    item['file_urls'] = [response.url]
    yield item
```

**In the crawler log it shows**

```
2016-06-20 16:10:26 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://example.com/page>
{'crawldate': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 20, 16, 10, 24, 824000),
 'file_urls': ['http://example.com/page'],
 'files': [{'checksum': 'checksumvalue',
            'path': 'full/hashedfile',
            'url': 'http://example.com/page'}],
 'pageurl': 'http://example.com/page',
 'title': u'My Example Page'}
```

The ideal structure for each csv line would be

> crawldate,file_url,file_path,title

Comment: Having looked at the files produced by the default FilesPipeline in some cases a file extension (.php) was provided but 1 file in a currently small sample

Answer (score 1):

If you want custom formats and such you probably want to just use good ol' [scrapy item pipelines.](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html)

in pipelines methods `process_item` or `close_spider` you can write your item to file. Like:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if not getattr(spider, 'csv', False):
        return item
    with open('{}.csv'.format(spider.name), 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow([item['crawldate'],item['title']])
    return item
```

This will write out `<spider_name>.csv` file every time you run the spider with `csv` flag, i.e. `scrapy crawl twitter -a csv=True`

You can make this more efficient if you open a file in `spider_open` method and close it in `spider_close`, but it's the same thing otherwise.

Comment: Would using the default feed exports available from the command line `--output` improve the structure of the data without needing to create my own item pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to avoid the need to clean the csv data by specifying the [xml output](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#simplest-way-to-dump-all-my-scraped-items-into-a-json-csv-xml-file) option instead of csv

Outputting as .xml then importing into Excel gave me a cleaner dataset of 1 row per page and without extra punctuation characters to preprocess